# Why is my photo on the wrong side?

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

[image]

```
\subsubsection{Upphängningsmetod}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{metod.jpeg}
    \caption{Figuren hängs från en av de tre punkterna och det hölls en tråd med en vikt precis vid punkten för att sedan rita lodlinjen. }
    \label{fig:metod}
\end{figure}
```

This is the code I have for the photo and it should look like the first photo but when I view the pdf file it's on the wrong side.
[image][image]

Comment: That won't happen all by itself. What rotation does the image have when you view it through an image viewer?

Comment: Please provide small but complete document, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: i updated the post with the image only @Werner

Comment: @Zarko how do you mean, do you mean with all my packages?

Comment: I mean to provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which in preamble has loaded only to problem related package. If your image is as you show in question, than you somewhere (probably in preamble) require, that it should be rotated ...

Comment: @Muhashka: See [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Comment: How did you upload that picture? I bet you it has a rotation flag which this forum software is stripping out. So you think the image is vertically orientated, but that is an illusion. Send a link (dropbox etc) to the actual image on your disk.

Answer (score 4):

LaTex does not respect image orientation tags (which is as it should be). HTML in websites does not support the tag either so you can get the same troubles.

If you take a picture on your phone or with some cameras, the camera injects an Exif orientation flag.

The image is always stored in one particular orientation (e.g portrait with the top of the camera being the top of the stored picture). However the camera also knows (via a sensor) whether and how you rotated the camera to take the shot (4 possible rotations in general).

When you view the picture on some image viewers (but not others) the image **appears**  to be upright - but in fact it is not.

Try opening the image in Irfanview (a great free bit of software). Click click Image -> Information, and then in the box that comes up click on the "EXIF info" button (the button will only be there is there is EXIF information embedded in the image). In the EXIF Info you may see an "orientation flag" which says which side of the image should **appear** to be on top (if the viewer supports such reorientation).

IrfanView in showing an image respects (or does not respect) the Exif info flag depending on the settings in the software (Options -> Properties/Settings, JPG/PCD/GIF and see box Auto-rotate image according to EXIF info - if available). For working in LaTex or on websites it is best to have this switched off.

This will give you the information you need to know whether you need to rotate the image yourself, or have Latex do that.

(I think there is a difficulty with this forum that when posters upload images that are causing problems, the forum software processes the image in various ways, so that the problem will not be apparent when re-downloaded into an MWE).

Just as a test I am uploading an image which is not only flipped but also turned into a mirror image in the original, but is only shown in its "correct" orientation as as result of flags

[image]

In fact the forum software not only incorrectly interprets the EXIF flag (it corrects one flip but not another), but also does strip it out.

A variety of test images with various flags are here: https://github.com/recurser/exif-orientation-examples
(the particular image uploaded below is Landscape_5)